# Remove background color from arrow

Tags: css

i have this css code to add one arrow to my dropdown:

```
div {
 &.toggle-assessment-key-dropdown {
   margin-top: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #cdd1da;
   min-width: 180px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   min-height: auto;
   padding: 6px 10px 5px 9px;
   background: #ffffff;
   position: absolute;
   top: 24px;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 501;

   &:after {
     content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 27%;
      margin-left: 8px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-bottom: 6px solid #cdd1da;
      border-right: 6px solid transparent;
      border-left: 6px solid transparent;
      border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
      border-width: 6px;
      background: #cdd1da;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I would like to remove grey corner but keep grey border:

Thank you

Comment: You cannot do that. Instead, there is a trick to accomplish your desire output. You can simply create another triangle arrow with a 1px bigger than the white and place the white triangle inside that gray triangle. Also, you will have to play with z-index.

Comment: thank you, could you add some code? thanks!

Comment: Sure, if you create a code snippet to create that dropdown or fiddle will help. I can give you a working demo.

Comment: i don't know how to create a code snippet. thank you!

Comment: In your question plesae add your html too and more scss that `&` is referring.

Comment: it's a simple div. Thank you!

Comment: just remove the `background: #cdd1da;` on `&:after`?

Comment: Please check below snippet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created snippet according to requirement, Currently done with css, you can make scss or i will create a pen let me know. please check:

```css
div.toggle-assessment-key-dropdown {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cdd1da;
  min-width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: 6px 10px 5px 9px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 501;
}
  div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 26%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #cdd1da transparent;
    border-width: 7px;
    
  }
  div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 27%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
    border-width: 5px;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="toggle-assessment-key-dropdown">
Item
</div>
```